# Add properties to context when rendering partial in Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Is it possible to add properties to context when rendering a partial template with handlebars.js?

```
{{> MyTemplate { X: Y }}}
```

I have a shared template that I need to insert some values to, depending on from which "master" template it is used.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this directly inside the call to the partial, no.  But you can pass context into a partial, provided you already have it available in the wrapping context.

In order to "embed" data in a context, you can use a helper that sets a private variable, like so:

```
<div>
  {{makeVar 'mode' 33}}
  <span>mode: {{@mode}}</span><!-- will return mode: 33 -->
</div>
```

Then, by passing something dynamic from context into the `makeVar` helper, you can compute a value for `@mode` which will then be added into the current context.

You could also modify the context itself, or merge the context with computed data on the fly.  (*Be careful:* doing it that way affects downstream users of the context as well.)

So, you could call the partial like this, and let the wrapping context set `@mode` accordingly.

```
<div>
  {{> myPartial .}}<!-- inside partial, @mode is accessible, along with context -->
</div>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/mcw0933/Cy64X/